# How to return an Iterator trait with mutable ref as Item?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to return an `Iterator` trait with a mutable ref as `item`. And I can't figure out why I am having this compiler error 
`cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements` and also `expected &mut T, found &mut T` for this code:

```rust
pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut T> {
    self.handles
        .iter_mut()
        .filter(|h| h.is_dirty == false)
        .map(move |h| &mut self.data[h.value])
}
```

Also the immutable version of it works well without any compiler errors:

```rust
pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
    self.handles
        .iter()
        .filter(|h| h.is_dirty == false)
        .map(move |h| &self.data[h.value])
}
```

I tried to clarify the compiler with some lifetimes, but I keep having this error.

I setup a playground here https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e399936f341d26c742a5e7e0bac4d89 (L138).

Also, I tried to implement the `iter_mut()` method myself (as https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#560) but without success. Same error, and even if I bypass this error, `handles` is scoped so the lifetime would not follow.

```rust
pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> IterMut<'_, &T> {
    let handles: Vec<&T> = self.handles
        .iter()
        .filter(|h| h.is_dirty == false)
        .map(move |h| &self.data[h.value])
        .collect();

    unsafe {
        let ptr = handles.as_mut_ptr();
        let end = ptr.add(handles.len());

        IterMut {
            ptr,
            end,
            _marker: marker::PhantomData
        }

    }
}
```

If one of you have any idea for this error, don't hesitate! :)
Thanks!

Comment: If this were to compile, and `self.handles` contained the same index twice, you could use this iterator to get two `&mut` references to the same element.